# How to get Slideshow in category using Custom Layout Update

Tags: magento-1.7, category, layout

I have used this code in Custom Layout Update of specific category

```
<reference name="content">
        <block type="dynamicslideshow/list" name="dynamicslideshow.list.default">
            <action method="setConfig"></action>
        </block>
</reference>
```

But It is showing at the end of All Products like this http://prntscr.com/auk8zt

Can anyone help in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **before="-"**

```
<reference name="content">
        <block type="dynamicslideshow/list" before="-" name="dynamicslideshow.list.default">
            <action method="setConfig"></action>
        </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: Great Bro, It helped, thanx a lot :)

Comment: It is showing after Page Title, Can i Do something to get page Title on top?

Comment: sure you can but you need to call your new block in : <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">

Comment: How & for a specific category?

Comment: add your xml to category custom view via backend